# Which tools use the "tests" directory in an Ansible role by default?

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

The `ansible-galaxy` tool can create a skeleton of an Ansible role. (`ansible-galaxy role init myrolename`) Inside is a `tests` directory, but the [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-directory-structure) [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/galaxy.html#create-roles) does not mention what it's for. Presumably tests of some sort, but who runs them, and how?

Answer (score 1):

**Travis CI.**

The `tests` directory seems to have been added in 2015, in PR [#13489](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/13489), and its description makes it clear that it's for Travis. It also adds `.travis.yml`, which looks like it does nothing by default. Snippet:

```yaml
script:
  # Basic role syntax check
  - ansible-playbook tests/test.yml -i tests/inventory --syntax-check
```

I am not aware of any other tools using it.

Comment: The inventory is not needed because you can do the same thing as:

ansible-playbook tests/test.yml -i localhost, --syntax-check

Comment: @bbaassssiiee I understand that. I just copied the snippet verbatim from the autogenerated `.travis.yml` file to show that it doesn't really do anything by default.